# Using Perl to connect to MS SQL without use of an ODBC DSN

Tags: sql-server, database, perl

Is there a way to use Perl to connect to a MS SQL database without the use of ODBC? I have a few scripts running in my production environment which I intend to migrate to perl.

Sample SQLCMD used:

```
sqlcmd -S <dbHostName> -i <input_file> -o <output_file>
```

Sample BCP used:

```
bcp <sqlQuery> queryout <output_file> -c -t, -T -S <dbHostName>
```

The main reason is that I do not know the password to my production database, and I cannot have knowledge of it. Therefore there is no way I can pass in the pass phrase whether in my perl script or via the ODBC setup.

Comment: How does the present code connect to the database, then?

Comment: Check the `FreeTDS` - AFAIK the only native way to connect to SQL Server. Alternatively, check whether you can create and manipulate a temporary ODBC connection from the script. Alternatively 2, check for possible solutions with Visual Basic, and convert them to Perl with the help of the `Win32::OLE` module ([example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905872%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)).

Comment: @choroba we are executing sqlcmd and bcp via windows batch file. We are going to migrate them into perl and add additional processing logic.

Comment: If the DBAs give rights out as needed to AD users then including `Trusted_Connection=True;` in your connection string will pass along the user's AD credentials without your needing to include them in your program.  As your `sqlcmd` does not include `-U` and `-P` this is likely your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that your `sqlcmd` statement does not include `-U` and `-P`.  This means it is using the logged-in user's credentials to access the database.

To accomplish the same with ODBC & DBI, include `Trusted_Connection=True;` in the connection string.  This is akin to using the "With Windows NT authentication using the network login ID." radio button on the 2nd page of the DSN setup wizard.

For example on my Win 8.1 box, where `SQL Server` is the name of the relevant *driver* (not DSN) in my ODBC Data Source Administration interface, I might give the DBI connect method the following string:

> dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

In contrast a string using a DSN might look like:

> dbi:ODBC:myDSN

FWIW: I find http://connectionstrings.com to be a valuable resource.

Comment: This means I have to setup ODBC? I would like to avoid having to do this where possible.

Comment: @louisxie What do you mean "setup ODBC"?  If you're running on Windows, ODBC is already installed.  If you're asking whether you need to set up a DSN, not if you properly craft your connection string.  If you're running on *nix, then, depending on your distro, you may in fact need to do some setup.

Comment: yes i meant adding a new DSN through the ODBC Data Source Administration. Do you mean I can connect to a database via ODBC without having to add the DSN? Sorry if i am asking a silly question. But if you do have a properly crafted connection string, could you kindly provide me a sample? I am currently using a windows machine.

Comment: I'm a big fan of `connectionstrings.com`.  How's [this `Trusted_Connection` example](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/trusted-connection/) work for you? A more general set of examples for SQL 2012 can be found [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/).

Comment: @louisxie Oh, and to be clear in the DBI connect method, the ODBC connection string should be preceded with `dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};`.  Concatenate those two strings.  BTW: `SQL Server` is the name of the driver as it appears in the ODBC DSA interface on my Win 8.1 machine.  Feel free to adjust...